# Opencart install module with vqmod

Tags: php, module, opencart, vqmod

I just started to learn **open cart** and I'm trying to install a new module using **VQMod**; any tutorials or any help? (I have the files in model view and controller but when I try to access them from the URL it says "permission denied")

Answer (score 0):

for access to installed module you must go to System>Users>User Group>Administrator
and click to "select all" under box access permission and modify permission